# Issue uploading images

Tags: bug, images

I encountered an issue today while uploading an image related to my answer to this question. [$\pi$ from the unit circle, $\sqrt 2$ from the unit square but what about $e$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387746/pi-from-the-unit-circle-sqrt-2-from-the-unit-square-but-what-about-e/387758#387758)

When I clicked on the icon to add an image and uploaded the image from my computer, a new tab with the link "https://math.stackexchange.com/upload/image" opens but the image does not get uploaded. The small window on the initial screen says "Uploading..." but it never gets uploaded. (In the end, I gave up and added the image to my dropbox public folder and added the link to the answer.)

I wanted to upload a screenshot of what is happening but again I am unable to do so on meta as well.

Comment: You can upload your screenshot to imgur directly, and post a link here.

Comment: @75064 Thanks. I have done that now. But the bug still remains.

Comment: I was able to upload your image (but you had edited the post in the meantime, so I had to cancel the edit). Have you tried restarting your browser?

Comment: @user17762 I meant you could use the imgur (or dropbox) workaround to post the screenshot of what is happening.

Comment: @robjohn Yes. I tried restarting the browser. I am on Google chrome browser on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @robjohn Could you allow me to change my username? It says I need to wait for another $30$ days!

Comment: @user17762: sure. What would you like?

Comment: @robjohn "Bil Dubque" Thanks.

Comment: @robjohn Could you change my name to user17762 on all stackexchange accounts? My philosophy, physics, tex accounts still have the name Bill Dubuque. Thanks

Comment: @user17762: I have asked that this be done (I cannot do anything to your non-math accounts myself).

Comment: @robjohn But I am unable to change the name on my non-math accounts. If I try to change it, it says "Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
Display name may only be changed once every 30 days; you may change again on Jun 12 at 7:14"

Comment: @user17762: That is why I have asked the powers that be to do it. I can only handle math information.

Comment: @user17762 Sorry about the delay. I have pushed your name change across the network.

Comment: @GraceNote Thanks.